# Parsing file into Hashtable in OCaml

Tags: parsing, ocaml

I'm trying to learn functional programming and having difficulty expressing a file parsing task functionally.
Let's say I have a text file with the following format:

```
val_0:       <--- "header"
key_0_0      <--- these keys should be set to the "header" or val0
key_0_1
key_0_2
...
...
val_n:     
...
key_n_m
```

How can I end up with a hash table with all keys set to their associated value?

EDIT: My solution. Can anyone improve it?

```
open Core.Std

let contains s1 s2 =
        let re = Str.regexp_string s2 in
        try ignore (Str.search_forward re s1 0); true
        with Not_found -> false


let read_db f = 
        let tbl = Caml.Hashtbl.create 123456 in
        let lines = In_channel.read_lines f in
        let src = ref "" in
        List.iter ~f:(fun g -> if contains g ":" then src := else Caml.Hashtbl.add tbl g !src) lines;
        tbl
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my solution, just for comparison.

```
let line_opt ic =
    try Some (input_line ic) with End_of_file -> None

let fold_lines_in f init fn =
    let ic = open_in fn in
    let rec go accum =
        match line_opt ic with
        | None -> accum
        | Some line -> go (f accum line)
    in
    let res = go init in
    close_in ic;
    res

let hashtable_of_file fn =
    let ht = Hashtbl.create 16 in
    let itab label line =
        let len = String.length line in
        if line.[len - 1] = ':' then
            String.sub line 0 (len - 1)
        else
            let () = Hashtbl.add ht line label in
            label
    in
    let _ = fold_lines_in itab "" fn in
    ht
```

**Update**

(Fixed non-tail-recursive fold implementation, sorry.)

Answer (score 0):

Waving from the future as this requires OCaml library features that were not available at the time the question was asked.

*`String.ends_with` was added in OCaml 4.13.0. And sequences in OCaml 4.07.0.*

Setting aside all of the file reading, we can do this without the imperative style `Hashtbl` using just `Map` and list folds.

We'll build up a list using `fold_left` by keeping the current key and a reversed association list of values, then later reversing both the association list and the values in each sublist, and then converting to a `Map`.

```
module SM = Map.Make (String)

let data = "val_0:\nhello\nworld\nval_1:\nfoo\nval_2:\nbar"
let data' = String.split_on_char '\n'

data' 
|> List.fold_left 
  (fun (cur_key, lst as acc) line ->
     let label = String.ends_with ~suffix:":" line in
     match cur_key with
     | None when label -> (Some line, (line, [])::lst)
     | Some _ when label -> (Some line, (line, [])::lst)
     | None -> acc
     | Some cur_key' -> (cur_key, let ((key, lst')::tl) = lst in (key, line::lst')::tl)
   )
  (None, [])
|> snd 
|> List.map (fun (k, v) -> (k, List.rev v)) 
|> List.rev
|> List.to_seq
|> SM.of_seq
```

If we get run `SM.bindings` on this value we can see that it has worked:

```
[("val_0:", ["hello"; "world"]); ("val_1:", ["foo"]); ("val_2:", ["bar"])]
```